# Installing new version of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

When I installed rails at an earlier period from the command line, I did it from my home directory. My question is, when I install a newer version, should I create a new project and install the new version in that directory? If I install the new version from the home directory and then create a new project directory and create a new rails project with the version specified, will it cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the new version right in your home directory, this is perfectly acceptable and even common.  The Rails executable (the file run by `rails new myCoolThing`) will default to the newest version of rails when you create a new project.  You can override this if you like by passing the version as an argument `rails <version> new myOldSchoolThing` when you create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on sticking with Rails you need to get a version manager program. The two most popular are RVM and Rbenv. I use RVM and it is very good. With that you can set up multiple Ruby and Rails environments with different Ruby, Rails and gem versions that apply to specific apps. Otherwise you will run into problems with multiple apps using different versions.

Here's the link https://rvm.io/